# Structured, reportable interactions in Experience Cloud Chatter Groups

Tags: experience-cloud, campaign, email-tracking, chatter-groups, publisher-action

To overcome the volume limitations of **native Salesforce Email Campaigns**, we switched to Experience Cloud Groups published to the original campaign members.

In our Email campaigns, we used **Links and Tracking** to ask recipients questions and reported and acted on their responses.

Now with Microcommunities in Group Chatter, we have way more ways to interact, like Chatter Feeds, Polls, Questions and Custom Chatter Publishers. But I still wrap my head around how to formalize this a bit.

1. I don't want the managers of such Groups to **collect feedback manually** just by following the members activities.
2. I want ways to respond automatically or **report on structured data**.
3. I also don't want all content and responses to be seen by all other
   members. So are there ways to have **hidden feedback channels** beyond
   Private Chatter messages?

**Can this be done by Custom Apex, Trigger, Flows, SOQL on Chatter objects? And how?**